GNOME session systematically drops
The user session systematically drops when I'm working in Ubuntu 24.04 and goes to the login screen.
It happens more often when I have two or more applications open, for example Krita and Chrome, or Krita and Spotify or all 3 together.
System details report:
Report Details
Created Date: 2024-12-08 11:15:35
##Device Information:

Device Model: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 3060
Memory: 8.0 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-8100T × 4
Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
Disk Capacity: 500.1 GB
##Software Information:

Firmware Version: 1.29.0
OS Name: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build: (null)
OS Type: 64-bit
Windows Version: GNOME:** 46
Window Manager: Wayland
Kernel Version: Linux 6.8.0-49-lowlatency

